# Setting the row value to previous value in a while loop when a condition is met

Tags: python-3.x, sap-gui

I am trying to re-set the row value to previous row value if a condition met. Once the condition is met the existing row get deleted.

```
for b in BR:
while i < cntRows:
    rowValue= session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").GetCellValue(i,"ZCOMMENTS")
    print(rowValue)
    if rowValue!="Orphan Impound":
        if debitAmt==disRcvAmt:
            impMatch="Dollar Amount Matched"
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").currentCellRow=i
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").selectedRows=i
            session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[13]").press()
            i-=1
        else:
            i+=1
continue
```

The code crashes when it goes back to the previous row when i use i-=1 and when the row counter is 0 it needs to go to the next item in b.

How do i stop the crash in both these scenarios.

Thanks Ren

Comment: "The code crashes" -- with which error? "when the row counter is 0 it needs to go to the next item in b" -- why doesn't your ``while`` loop check for ``i == 0`` then? What's the initial value of ``i``?

Comment: Initial value of i==0. I checks that as well  cntRow = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").RowCount
                                    if cntRow==0:  I have added this in the if condition still does not work.

Comment: There is no error as the application is unable to find it and the code is in a try and except block

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the the solution and stopped the crash by adding this part

```
cntRow=session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").RowCount
if cntRow <0:
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(3)
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(2)
    break
elif cntRow==i:
    break
elif cntRow>0:
    if k<0:
       i=-1
    else:
       i==k
```